# Google Sheets: How to access responses tab after creating form via script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My Google Sheets script programmatically creates a form, and then attempts to change the name of the `Form Responses` tab that was added to the spreadsheet.  The form is created fine, but I can't seem to access the responses tab, at least from the same function.  It appears that the `Sheets` object is not getting updated with the new tab.

However, if I run a separate function later that tries to access the responses tab, this works fine.

Any suggestions for how to get the Spreadsheet to update and reflect the new set of Sheets?  I was hoping I could use something like a `setTimeout` but doesn't sound like that is available in Google script. A time-based trigger wouldn't work because I want this function to be able to happen quickly (not after a minute).

Comment: Show the code you're using that fails, if you're using code but it fails...

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks!  `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` did it!  I tried `Utilities.sleep` before but that didn't work.  Much appreciated!